# Can you open a smart object as copy?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-camera-raw

In Adobe Camera Raw, I know of 3 options for opening files in Photoshop:

1. If you click the `Open Image` button, it saves your changes to a sidecar xmp file (or database if you've set it up that way) and opens as a raster image in Photoshop.
2. If you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click the (now) `Open Copy` button, it only opens as a raster image
3. If you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the (now) `Open Object` button, it saves your changes to a xmp file and opens as a smart object in Photoshop

Is there no way to "Open Object as Copy", i.e., open as a smart object without saving the changes to a xmp file?